# Visual Studio 10: Setting my default browser doesn't stick

Tags: browser, visual-studio-2010

I've tried setting my default browser to Firefox (for development purposes), but my machine's default browser is Chrome. It works when I set it in VS, but if I close VS and then open it again, it reverts back to chrome as my default. In VS08 my preference stuck. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the VS extension: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb424812-f742-41ef-974a-cdac607df921.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible yet.

See this:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/568469/vs2010-forgets-default-browser-settings