# How to choose with which browser Visual Studio 2012 opens hyperlinks?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual Studio 10: Setting my default browser doesn’t stick](https://superuser.com/questions/198738/visual-studio-10-setting-my-default-browser-doesnt-stick)

Is there any way to make Visual Studio 2012 default to an external browser when opening a hyperlink from it and, if so, how? By default, hyperlinks opened from Visual Studio will open in a new tab with VS's built in browser, while I would prefer to have the links open in my current browser. Changing the browser which is used for running does not change how hyperlinks are opened.

I have seen several ways to change the default browser for running programs by choosing a browser in the "Browse With..." option in the menu, but that does not change how hyperlinks open, and the accepted answer for [Visual Studio 10: Setting my default browser doesn't stick](https://superuser.com/questions/198738/visual-studio-10-setting-my-default-browser-doesnt-stick) only works for Visual Studio 2010, not VS 2012. EDIT: On further inspection of the other question, it seems to be purely about running the program and, even in VS 2010, does not change how hyperlinks open.